# Flying through Sheremetyevo airport in Moscow considering current situation?

Tags: air-travel, safety, russia, moscow, svo

At the end of next month I will be going from Asia through Sheremetyevo airport in Moscow to some other European country. The carrier of choice is Aeroflot.

Considering what is happening now between Russia and Ukraine (including rest of those involved) should I reconsider using this carrier/route? Are there any problems right now with flights using Sheremetyevo international airport?

Update: Thank you all for the answers. It's good to know, that there are no problems at this moment with flights going through Sheremetyevo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There should be no problems, unless you're on a Ukrainian passport, according to the Russian in my team here.  Even then it should be fine, you may just experience some questions on your reason for your trip.  Of course, as you're just continuing on to Europe, you're going to get very little attention.

In terms of the city, it's far from Ukraine and the situation in Crimea. At present, it's fine.  Sure, *something* might happen between now and then, but it seems unlikely at present.

Your best bet is to make sure you have travel insurance, just in case - but it's unlikely that it'll need to come into play.

Also check with your country's travel advisory alerts for Russia.  For example [Australia's advisory](http://smartraveller.gov.au/zw-cgi/view/Advice/Russia) points out that in addition to the Crimea incidents, there have been bombings in recent months, including terrorist attacks in Moscow.  But again, it's unlikely, and right now, flights through Sheremetyevo are proceeding as normal.

Answer (score 1):

@Mark Mayo is quite right in his opinion - Aeroflot isn't involved into politic conflict, and, as your route isn't connected with Ukraine, you should not get any problems there. As soon as I understand, you'll even not leave the Transit zone, so all your time in Sheremetyevo you'll be in safe zone with not much attention from others.

Security checks can be everythere, but, if your documents are fine and you are polite and not looking for conflict, I think everything will be OK.

As for the terrorists attacks, Moscow isn't very dangerous region from this point of view, South regions of Russia is more.

---

Update: Security restrictions for Olimpic and Paraolimpic games are now canseled by Sheremetyevo ([link in Russian](http://itar-tass.com/obschestvo/1077966))

Answer (score 0):

Right now, things at Moscow airports are pretty much normal. If I was going to fly there a week from now, I wouldn't worry too much. A month from now, all bets are off.

As long as the economic sanctions against Russia remain nominal, targeting only a few key personnel, the situation should remain normal for the rest of us. However, if Russia doesn't give in and return Crimea to Ukraine (which doesn't seem likely), some real sanctions are probably going to take place. When that happens, there may be severe restrictions for flights between Russia and EU.

Iraq did a similar thing in 1990. Because it was only a regional power, the rest of the world went to war to reverse the annexation of Kuwait. Russia is a much bigger player, so nobody is seriously considering a military intervention. Still, I would be very surprised, if the future developments did not seriously inconvenience pretty much everyone traveling to Russia for business, leisure, or transit.

I should be going to a conference in Moscow in June, but I've been delaying travel arrangements and visa application to the last possible moment. Unfortunately that last possible moment will be in a couple of weeks, and there are no signs of the situation getting resolved before that.